# Matlab : Writing the output into csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have some data which includes string and numbers I want to store them in a csv file.
The numbers which are the out put of a function is stored in an array of 1x20.
So in the csv file, I want to have 21 columns! So, the first column in csv file should be the string, and the next 20 columns have the information in 1x20 array.
How can I do that?

I used something like this to make a 1x21 cell:

> % str : string variable; arr : 1x20 array of numbers
>
> c = cell(1,21);
>
> c{1,1} = str;
>
> for cnt = 2 : 21
>
> c{1,cnt} = arr(1,cnt-1);
>
> end

Then I tried below code that has been offered in this [link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/70018-how-to-write-cell-array-into-a-csv-file):

```
fid = fopen('test.csv', 'w') ;
fprintf(fid, '%s,', c{1,1:end-1}) ;
 fprintf(fid, '%s\n', c{1,end}) ;
 fclose(fid) ;
 dlmwrite('test.csv', c(2:end,:), '-append') ;
```

, but I can't see the exact data inside the csv. For example, I have `arr(1,1) = 1.0000`. However the second column is empty in the csv file !!!

Can anyone help me solving this problem?

---

UPDATE:
The answers did not work :(
Let me ask my question in a different way and make it a bit clear. 
I want to have some data like below in my csv file:

`path, feat1, feat2, feat3, feat4
 C:\mydata\First\,10,2.001,450,12
 C:\mydata\Second\,11,4.41,250,11
 C:\mydata\Third\,20,3.891,289,10`

So, each row of data has one string in first column and 4 numbers in the followings. 
These 4 numbers are the output of a function as an array. So imaging `str` is the string and `output` is the array of 4 numbers. So, I want to add a part into the below cod that can store the result in the format I mentioned above into a csv file.

```
path1 = "C:\mydata\First\";
path2 = "C:\mydata\Second\";
path3 = "C:\mydata\Third\";
output = [];

for i = 1:3
    str = eval(sprintf("path%d",i));
    output = myFunction(str); % output is an array of data
    %%The code I need to add here to store the data in a csv file%%
 end
```

I hope it is clear now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown the code which write data to .csv file. However, this might help [link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/70018-how-to-write-cell-array-into-a-csv-file)

Comment: I've already seen this link. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the solution:

```
path1 = "C:\mydata\First\";
path2 = "C:\mydata\Second\";
path3 = "C:\mydata\Third\";
output = [];
fid = fopen('test.csv', 'w') ;
for i = 1:3
    str = eval(sprintf("path%d",i));
    output = myFunction(str); % output is an array of data
    %%The code I need to add here to store the data in a csv file%%
    fprintf(fid, '\n%s,', str) ;
    for cnt = 1:4
        fprintf(fid, '%d,', output(1,cnt));
    end
 end
fclose(fid) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation states:

```
dlmwrite(filename,M,'-append') appends the data to the end of the existing file, filename.
```

which is not what you want: you want to append to each line. So all values are added after the Strings.
You probably have to do something like:

```
for i = 1:20
   fprintf(fid, '%s,');
   dlmwrite('test.csv', c{2:end,:}, '-append');
end
```

1. I am not sure if the file should be closed after each `fprintf` though. You should check it yourself.
2. I am not sure for the syntax involving cells. You don't get any advantage by using them since you never address the cell as a whole.

Consider using a simple matrix for the values which would work just fine:

```
dlmwrite('test.csv', c(2:end,:), '-append');
```

And use cell for the String part only if you want (or struct).

Edit:

OK here a tested working approach for your problem:

```
fid = fopen('testing.txt', 'w');
A = rand(4,3);
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    String = sprintf('Line: %d', i);
    fprintf(fid, sprintf('%s, %1.2f, %1.2f, %1.2f\n', String, A(i,:)));
end
fclose(fid);
```

If you don't want to explicitly specify the number of element in the matrix `A` then even a solution like this works in Matlab (since it repeats the `?print` command for every element):

```
fid = fopen('testing.txt', 'w');
A = rand(4,3);
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    String = sprintf('Line: %d', i);
    fprintf(fid, sprintf('%s,', String));
    fprintf(fid, sprintf('%1.2f,', A(i,:)));
    fprintf(fid, '\n');
end
fclose(fid);
```

I hope that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save `2:20` columns of the cell, you need to use normal parenthesis as follows:

```
c(1,cnt)=arr(1,cnt-1);
```

And for writing a `csv` file with mixed datatypes, `csvwrite` does not work. Please see **Thanushan Balakrishnan** comment.